cyrus-imapd - cyrus.conf why does the ipuge command not purge stale messages
I have an cyrus-imap-3 installation that does not appear to be properly configured to remove stale messages from users mailboxes.  But I cannot see what is wrong. If somebody can point out my error then I would be grateful.
The entries in cyrus.conf include:
SERVICES {
  # add or remove services based on preferences
  imap          cmd="imapd" listen="imap" prefork=0
  imaps         cmd="imapd -s" listen="imaps" prefork=0

  # at least one LMTP is required for delivery
  lmtp          cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
  lmtpunix      cmd="lmtpd" listen="/var/imap/socket/lmtp" prefork=0

}

EVENTS {
  # this is required
  checkpoint    cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=30
. . .
 flushLakDfd cmd="ipurge -X -d 35  -f user/luserl/delivery/forwarding" at=0414
. . .

But when I look into the users mailbox I see this:
find /var/spool/imap/l/user/luserl/delivery/forwarding -name "*\." -maxdepth 1 -mtime +35 -type f | wc -l
   9219

For example: (added)
cyrus-imapd30-3.0.17_1

%find /var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash -type f -mtime +1000 -name "*\."
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231929.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231930.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231928.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/226715.
%
% ./sbin/ipurge  -f -d 1000 user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash
%
% find /var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash -type f -mtime +1000 -name "*\."
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231929.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231930.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/231928.
/var/spool/imap/b/user/byrnejb_hll/INBOX^Trash/226715.



Do you have cyr_expire periodic invocation in cyrus.conf? What it logs when it runs?

delprune      cmd="cyr_expire -D 180d -E 3d -X 180d" at=0400

/var/log/maillog:Oct  3 04:04:28 imap CYRUS/cyr_expire[55339]: Expired 0 and expunged 1620 out of 1040557 messages from 3536 mailboxes

Well, apparently it's set to keep \Deleted messages for 180 more days if you have delete_mode: delayed, the default, in imapd.conf. It's set with -X 180d. Probably this is the reason? I've never seen it set for that long.

Per the example added above the ipurge utility is not purging messages that themselves are more than 1000 days old.
